# Attempting to validate username (email address) and password - having issues - vb.net

Tags: vb.net, validation, email, passwords, credentials

I have a Windows Form app that is not properly validating the user input information. Need some help.
I inserted the Microsoft Login form and am writing code to verify the user credentials.  Using an Access DB to store and retrieve info. Two tables - one for email address and another for password.
I verify format of the email addy using regex.  This works very well. 
I validate the email address is in correct form and verify it is in the table (this works well). Then I attempt to read the password (appears this is not working as expected) and then read both bits of information from the tables. Next, I test to make sure both are present.  If both are present control is passed to another form.

My issue is reading/verifying the password.

Here is my Visual Studio VB.net code.

```
Private Sub OK_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles OK.Click

    Try

        If MsgBox("Is your information correct?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "M&P Records") = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then

            Dim pattern As String = "^[A-Z][A-Z|0-9|]*[a-z][a-z|0-9|]*([_][a-z|0-9]+)*([.][a-z|0-9]+([_][a-z|0-9]+)*)?@[a-z][a-z|0-9|]*\.([a-z][a-z|0-9]*(\.[a-z][a-z|0-9]*)?)$"

            Dim match As System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match = Regex.Match(txtUsername.Text.Trim(), pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
            If (match.Success) Then


                Try
                    If i = 0 Then
                        provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="

                        'Change the following to your access database location
                        dataFile = "\11_2017_Spring\CSCI-2999_Capstone\DB_M&PRecords.accdb"

                        connString = provider & dataFile
                        myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
                        myConnection.Open()
                        i = 1
                    End If

                Catch ex As Exception
                    '  An error occured!  Show the error to the user and then exit.
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
                End Try


                'the query:

                Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [EmailAddress] WHERE [emailAddress] = '" & txtUsername.Text & "'", myConnection)
                Dim com As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Password] WHERE [Password] = '" & txtPassword.Text & "'", myConnection2)

                Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                Dim drp As OleDbDataReader = com.ExecuteReader()

                ' the following variable is hold true if EmailAddress is found, and false if EmailAddress is not found 
                Dim userFound As Boolean = False

                ' the following variable is hold true if Password is found, and false if Password is not found 
                Dim passwordFound As Boolean = False

                ' the following variables will hold the EmailAddress and Password if found.
                Dim EmailAddressText As String = ""
                Dim PasswordText As String = ""

                'if found:
                While dr.Read()
                    userFound = True
                    EmailAddressText = dr("EmailAddress").ToString
                End While

                While drp.Read()
                    passwordFound = True
                    PasswordText = drp("Password").ToString
                End While

                'checking the result
                If userFound = True And passwordFound = True Then
                    frmMain.Show()
                    frmMain.Label1.Text = "Welcome " & EmailAddressText & " "
                Else
                    MsgBox("Sorry, username or password not found", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "M&P Records - Invalid Login")

                    With txtPassword
                        .Clear()
                    End With

                    With txtUsername
                        .Clear()
                        .Focus()
                    End With

                End If

            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid email address", "M&P Records - Email Check")

                With txtPassword
                    .Clear()
                End With

                With txtUsername
                    .Clear()
                    .Focus()
                End With
            End If

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        '  An error occured!  Show the error to the user and then exit.
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Well first your approach isn't really safe due to the fact the the password isn't encrypted and that either there is no link between email and password ideally you would have table for example:

USER
--UID
--Email

PASS
--ID
--UID
--PASS

And you would hash your password for example sha512 furthermore for more security you would use Salt and certificates to secure the database connection.

Then you could do:
Hash current password in textbox and execute:

```
"SELECT USER.Email FROM USER,PASS WHERE USER.Email='TEXTBOX_EMAIL' AND USER.UID = PASS.UID"
```

Check if you have result if yes your connected.

However I tried to correct a bit what you did in the above code. Having used only SQLClient and not Olecommand i tried to keep what you did so there might be few syntax errors but should be ok:

```
Try
    If MsgBox("Is your information correct?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "M&P Records") = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
        Dim pattern As String = "^[A-Z][A-Z|0-9|]*[a-z][a-z|0-9|]*([_][a-z|0-9]+)*([.][a-z|0-9]+([_][a-z|0-9]+)*)?@[a-z][a-z|0-9|]*\.([a-z][a-z|0-9]*(\.[a-z][a-z|0-9]*)?)$"
        Dim match As System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match = Regex.Match(txtUsername.Text.Trim(), pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
        If (match.Success) Then
            Dim passwordFound As Boolean
            Dim userFound As Boolean
            Using con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source =\ 11_2017_Spring\CSCI-2999_Capstone\DB_M&PRecords.accdb")
                'Using to make sure connection is disposed
                'Open connection
                con.Open()
                'Prepare sql
                Dim command As New OleDbCommand("SELECT [emailAddress] FROM [EmailAddress] WHERE [emailAddress] = '" & txtUsername.Text & "';", con)
                'Create the reader
                Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
                Dim Id As String = ""
                ' Call Read before accessing data.
                While reader.Read()
                    'Get data
                    Id = reader(0)
                End While
                'Close Reader
                reader.Close()
                If Id <> "" Then
                    'User found
                    userFound = True
                    'Prepare the second sql 
                    Dim command2 As New OleDbCommand("SELECT [Password] FROM [Password] WHERE [Password] = '" & txtPassword.Text & "';", con)
                    'Prepare second reader
                    Dim reader2 As OleDbDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
                    Dim Pass As String = ""
                    ' Call Read before accessing data.
                    While reader2.Read()
                        'Get tdata
                        Pass = reader2(0)
                    End While
                    reader.Close()
                    If Pass <> "" Then
                        'Pass found
                        passwordFound = True
                    Else
                        passwordFound = False
                    End If
                Else
                    userFound = False
                End If
                'Close connection
                con.Close()
                'Clear connection pool
                SqlConnection.ClearPool(con)
            End Using
            'checking the result
            If userFound = True And passwordFound = True Then
                frmMain.Show()
                frmMain.Label1.Text = "Welcome " & EmailAddressText & " "
            Else
                MsgBox("Sorry, username or password not found", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "M&P Records - Invalid Login")
                With txtPassword
                    .Clear()
                End With
                With txtUsername
                    .Clear()
                    .Focus()
                End With
            End If
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid email address", "M&P Records - Email Check")
            With txtPassword
                .Clear()
            End With
            With txtUsername
                .Clear()
                .Focus()
            End With
        End If
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
    '  An error occured!  Show the error to the user and then exit.
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: thanks for the idea.  I understand the security issues yet this app is run on my laptop as a presentation only, not functional in the wild.  I am a beginner and this is a learning project for me,  so the switch to SQL proved somewhat of an issue for me.  my DB is as you said.  EMAIL - EID - emailaddy.  Pass - pass - EID.  Does this make a difference?  How can I use the Ole connection?

Comment: i suggest you do some research @user7662393, like a simple google :-
"How can I use the Ole connection?" even that will bring up something relevant

Comment: I have a basic understanding of Ole.  I do connect to and read from four tables in this DB that populate combo / list boxes.  With that said, I am not an expert but can connect and read from my DB.  I am unable to resolve the issue of reading from two tables to validate the user..  @Danny James.

Comment: @user7662393 Glad you took the simpler approach and hope my code managed to help you understand better how to handle sql connections. If you have any questions feel free to contact me.

Comment: @ Mederic Burlet  Thanks for your help and the offer. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Decided to combine the email and passwords into one table.  Made everything easier for now.  Thanks for your help and suggestions.